# isql (sql anywhere) updating NULL value

Tags: sql, sap-ase, isql

How can i change (NULL) value of a table? I have searched everywhere but didn't find the right answer.

Works, but updates 0 rows:

```
UPDATE Club 
SET Place = 24
WHERE Place = NULL;
```

Not working:

```
UPDATE Club 
SET Place = 24
WHERE Place IS NULL;
```

Comment: On Oracle DB the "Update Club SET Place = 24 WHERE Place IS NULL" works.

Comment: Correlation name 'Club' not found. <-- if i use IS NULL.

Comment: maybe isql doesn't support null try '' instead?

Comment: I've noticed that you have asked about something similar before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464454/isql-sql-anywhere-trigger-gives-error. Are you sure that you are connected to proper database and the table exists?

Comment: Still the same, updates 0 rows with '' and with 0, strange. And yes, Club is table.

Comment: @Michal Powaga, my other problem is almost solved, trigger is working, it just isn't working with the NULL. I have tested everything there, just the NULL value isn't updating.

Comment: @Slavak this is for sybase, oracle, sql server?

Comment: @aF, "Sybase" is a company not a product.  The product in this case is SqlAnywhere, not to confused with Adaptive Server Anywhere (ASE). Same company, completely different products.

Comment: @Slavak, there's no reason this should fail to update.  What do you get if you "Select * from Club where  Place is null" ?

Comment: @ElroyFlynn, It gives the right result, only the items that the Place is NULL, nothing more, it just wont update them.

Comment: try a full qualification of the table name, specifying the owner: both for the update and the select. (e.g., "dbo.Club")

Comment: Are there any triggers on this table?

Comment: @ElroyFlynn, yes there are, i will delete and rewrite them, so that there will be no NULLs. Thanks all of you and sorry for the trouble. Tomorrow i will try with a new clean table and post if it was my fault that the NULLs aren't updating.

Comment: What happens if you run `UPDATE Club SET Place = 24 WHERE Place = ''`;

Answer (score 0):

Something worth trying

```
Update Club
Set Place = 24
where CLUBID in (Select CLUBID from Club where place is NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Club 
SET Place = 24
WHERE Place IS NULL;
```

This works fine. If its not working then, you don't have records where Place is null.
Check with null case as well, as sql is case sensitive.

Comment: SQL is **not** case sensitive! Especially not with keywords